# Как правильно: «ни» или «не»?

Tags: частица-не, частица, не-или-ни, придаточное-предложение, ни

Какая должна быть частица в следующем предложении – «ни» или «не»?

*В какой стране мы бы «?» были, по улицам каких городов бы «?» ходили, самые счастливые моменты связаны с любимыми людьми.*

Answer (score 3):

В данном предложении нужно использовать усилительную частицу ***ни*** (а частица ***бы***, на мой взгляд, лучше звучит в другом месте):

*В какой бы стране мы **ни** были, по улицам каких бы городов **ни** ходили, самые счастливые моменты связаны с любимыми людьми.*

Из [справочника под ред. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=42):

> **§ 78.** Существуют особые конструкции с частицами ***не*** и ***ни.***
> <...>
> 2. И частица ***не***, и частица ***ни*** могут входить в конструкции с местоименными словами *кто, что* (в разных падежах), *как, где, куда, откуда* и т. п.
> <...>
> б) конструкции с местоименными словами и частицей ***ни*** (часто — с предшествующей частицей ***бы***) всегда являются частью уступительных придаточных предложений, напр.: *Каким бы ни был ответ, это лучше полной неизвестности. Где бы он ни работал, его всюду ценили. Когда бы к нему ни пришли, он всегда занят.*